# How rename a mongodb database

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I need to rename a MongoDB DB database programmatically. I have not seen a way to do this with the MongoDB c# driver.

I would like to do something like:
this.mongoClient.renameDatabase("oldName","newName");

I figure I can roll my own but I feel like this should be possible with a current driver.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible at the moment. You can follow [This JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-701).If you must do it for some reason, you'll need to Create a new DB with the new name and copy all collections, views, and buckets to the new database.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreJuma! I am creating a little method right now I'll go ahead and post it later.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that works for me. Granted, I am dealing with smaller databases but this can solve the problem for some.

```
/// <summary>
///  Renames old database to new database by copying all its collected contents
///  ToDO: Add checks and balances to ensure all items were transferred correctly over
///  Disclaimer: use at own risk and adjust to your needs
/// </summary>
/// <param name="currentName"></param>
/// <param name="newName"></param>
public void renameDatabase(string currentName, string newName)
{

    this.mongoClient.DropDatabase(newName); //we drop the new database in case it exists

    var newDb = mongoClient.GetDatabase(newName); //get an instance of the new db

    var CurrentDb = mongoClient.GetDatabase(currentName); //get an instance of the current db

    foreach (BsonDocument Col in CurrentDb.ListCollections().ToList()) //work thru all collections in the current db
    {
        string name = Col["name"].AsString; //getting collection name

        //collection of items to copy from source collection
        dynamic collectionItems = CurrentDb.GetCollection<dynamic>(name).Find(Builders<dynamic>.Filter.Empty).ToList();

        //getting instance of new collection to store the current db collection items
        dynamic destinationCollection = newDb.GetCollection<dynamic>(name);

        //insert the source items into the new destination database collection
        destinationCollection.InsertMany(collectionItems);
    }

    //removing the old datbase
    this.mongoClient.DropDatabase(currentName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

run a `renameCollection` command on the admin database for every collection name in your source db with the format:

`renameCollection: 'old.CollectionName', to: 'new.CollectionName'`

here's how to do it in c#:

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var dbAdmin = client.GetDatabase("admin");

var dbOldName = "old-db";
var dbNewName = "new-db";

var collections = client.GetDatabase(dbOldName).ListCollectionNames().ToList();

foreach (var collection in collections)
{
    var command = $"{{ renameCollection: '{dbOldName}.{collection}', to: '{dbNewName}.{collection}' }}";

    dbAdmin.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
}
```

Comment: @huuduy this is for renaming database. pls read the code carefully. you achieve it by renaming collections in the admin database. it's a hack.