# How to implement CommandDocument in MongoDB C# Driver version 2.1 without using the Legacy Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am upgrading an app that was using the Mongo v1 C# driver on the 3.x series engine.
I have upgraded the DB to 4.2 and the C# driver to 2.1 and made all of the necessary changes related to depreciated c# methods, etc.
However, there is one issue remaining. I have a couple of places where we run something similar to:

```
    var command = new CommandDocument { { "dbStats", 1 }, { "scale", 1 } };
                        var result = mongoDb.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
                        var tempSize = result["dataSize"].ToInt32();
```

I **DO NOT** want to load or use the "legacy driver".

What is the proper way using the new (non-legacy) c# driver to execute this type of command?
Thanks in advance for everyone's suggestions.

Comment: you can still use `RunCommand` in the v2 driver. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56829814/4368485) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

There's now a base abstract class of `Command<TResult>` where there is derived type of `BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>` this is similar to what you were using before.

The following code will do the same as your previous code

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("A");

var result = database.RunCommand(new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument {{"dbStats", 1}, {"scale", 1}}));

var tempSize = result["dataSize"].ToInt32();
```